# Teegris by samsung - which devices does it support?

Tags: samsung-mobile, tee

I need to make a POC for Trusted Execution Environment.
I need to know which Samsung devices are supported by the `TEEGris library`. Do you know ?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now Exynos 9820 and 9825 devices should be supported, Older exynos devices used MobiCore, Qcom samsung devices with snapdragon 855 might also be supported but im not sure on that one so your best bet is testing it on something like s10e SM-G970F as its cheapest of bunch